iPhone can't connect to metro on react-native 0.73.6
I have debug scheme, app is running on my iPhone. I allowed access to local network connections for my app, tried to configure bundle with my mac ip and 8081 port. When I try to refresh it seems to be ok, but metro bundler is not building new bundle and changes in code are not applied. In xcode I can see this error:

_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<132>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.6:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.6:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

I can access http://192.168.1.6:8081/status from iPhone's Safari, so there is no problem with IP and port configuration
What can be the problem?
Thank you

Restart your iPhone
FYI im using:

iPhone 12 Physical device running iOS 17.5.1

Xcode 15.3

RN 0.74.1


